# Display a dataframe larger in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, display

I create a dataframe by a csv file.

```py
df.to_csv('C:\\file.csv', index = False, header = True, encoding='latin1', sep = ';')
```

My dataframe is like :

| Id | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pedro-Sanchez **/n** Gomez |

It displays the first row on two row. When it is a long text with space, the dataframe display it to the line.

I want to display my dataframe like :

| Id | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pedro-Sanchez Gomez |

I use `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',None)` but it doesn't work.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python gives you a lot possibilities to deal with this.

Assume that your data looks like that: ['Pedro-Sanchez /n Gomez', 'Pedro-Sanchez /n Gomez']

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lista = ['Pedro-Sanchez /n Gomez', 'Pedro-Sanchez /n Gomez']
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.replace(" /n", "") for x in lista])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([x.split(" /n") for x in lista])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x.split(" /n") for x in lista]).flatten())
```

You have 3 options to handle with "/n":

- df1 - jest remove it
- df2 - divide it to two columns
- df3 - divide it to one columns

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use replace to remove this

`df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace('\n', '')`

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand your problem, you are trying to delete the /ns, you should use the regex for this.For example, you can customize it like this
res = []
for sub in test_list:
res.append(sub.replace("\n", ""))